# How to write a capybara matcher that checks that a div is empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm looking at the capybara matchers documentation: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers

I can't seem to find way to check that a `div` is blank. I.e. I want to verify the presence of something like

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

I thought about `assert_no_selector`, but I don't think text nodes within a `div` show up. `has_no_content` doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
assert_selector('div', class: 'test', text: '')
```

Comment: If the div actually has some text this will still pass. It seems like it should not, but is checking if the div contains `''`. Which will pass if the div contains text such as `'foo'`.

Comment: This test will give false positives. If anything inside text exists in the selector, the test will pass. Because "" always exists inside this selector, it will always pass.

Answer (score 4):

you can access div content with `find("#test").text`

Comment: Thanks, that let me test for an exact match to `<h1></h1>`

Comment: This depends on what driver you're using, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

something like assert_selector('div.test', text: /\A\Z/) should do what you want.  Passing a regex to the :text option allows you to do full text matching on the contents of the element.

Answer (score 1):

I use the CSS `:empty` selector:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('#my_element:empty')
```

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
expect(page).to have_css('.test', exact_text: '')
```

will work for you

Answer (score 0):

The following will work with a `test` **`class`**:

```
assert_selector('div.test', text: '')
```

If instead you were looking for a `test` **`id`**, then use this:

```
assert_selector('div#test', text: '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expect(page).to have_selector(:xpath, "//div[contains(@class, 'test') and normalize-space(string(.)) = '']")
```